# Remote Level Control in Serilog using Seq doesn't honor overrides?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, serilog, seq

I'm trying to control the minimum level of logs written to SEQ using remote level control in Serilog. However, it seems like this will ignore the overrides that I have set for individual log sources.

This is the config I have:

```
var logLevelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Warning);
var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(logLevelSwitch)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("MyApplication", LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Source", applicationName)
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .WriteTo.Seq(
        serverUrl: seqUrl,
        apiKey: seqApiKey,
        compact: true,
        eventBodyLimitBytes: 262144,
        batchPostingLimit: 40,
        controlLevelSwitch: logLevelSwitch);
```

If the level in SEQ is set to `Information` or `Warning`, then the `Debug` logs from `MyApplication` isn't being written. Is this expected?

For me it's easier to say: *"Only log `Warning`, but do log debug/info for these few specific sources."*

Comment: Aaahh. Just realized. Is the `Warning` applied as a filter on the SEQ side as well? I guess it is, it probably doesn't know about it being used as a remote level? So I'm guessing Serilog sends debug logs for MyApplication, but SEQ filters them out because of the Warning filter?

Comment: Yes, that's the case 